# Which part of MVC we consider while working with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller

I am new to ReactJS, i know we can consider MVC while working with ReactJS. My Question is 
ReactJS Focuses on which of the following part when considering MVC

- Model
- View
- Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is JavaScript library from Facebook, that is designed to create interactive UIs. The main features are that it’s
So, React is often referred to as the View in a MVC structure, Facebook presented their own architecture called Flux

Answer (score 2):

React is a library and not a framework. This mean that it provides only the "V" of MVC.
And although it manages views, the paradigm at its base is composition and the architecture is Flux, where data flow isn't bidirectional (like MVC) but instead flows unidirectionally from top to bottom.

Ref: https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/understanding-mvc-architecture-with-react-6cd38e91fefd